# Why google app engine is removing Spring web?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I am using the following Spring library:

```
spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
```

Everything seems to be fine for Eclipse until I click run/debug using the GAE SDK's server.
The library is there, just under app-name/war/WEB-INF/lib/.

Then this error appears:

> The archive: app-name/war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.

And then the library is removed from the app-name/war/WEB-INF/lib/ folder.

If I don't add the library in the Java Build Path directly but through the "Web App Libraries" (that refer to app-name/war/WEB-INF/lib/ ) I can run the Server, but a NoClassFoundException is thrown:

```
WARNING: Could not instantiate listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:215)
```

And also, after that the library is deleted from the path: app/war/WEB-INF/lib/

I read some documentation about how to run applications with the Spring Framework in google's developers page.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization

It doesn't say anything about removing libraries.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure to have `WEB-INF/lib` folder in the right level?

Comment: Yes, I was 100% sure. Now it works, I just delete the project in eclipse and load it again.
Thanks Luiggi

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it is being removed, but I had the same issue using Luna, AppEngine 1.9.30 and Spring Web 4.2.5 today. The fix was to use an older version of the spring-web jar: 3.1.4 worked for me. I also tried modifying the 4.2.5 jar, removing the services directory from the META-INF directory and more, to no avail.